# Is there a way to include ± (plus or minus) in python?

Tags: python

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I have had trouble finding an easy and concise answer. Any suggestions?
My code looks like this:

```
if int(guess1 == int(answer + 1) and guess2 == int(answer + 2))
    print("The answer was: " + answer + ". Player 1 wins!")
if int(guess1 == int(answer + 1) and guess2 == int(answer - 2))
        print("The answer was: " + answer + ". Player 1 wins!")
if int(guess1 == int(answer - 1) and guess2 == int(answer + 2))
    print("The answer was: " + answer + ". Player 1 wins!")
if int(guess1 == int(answer - 1) and guess2 == int(answer - 2))
        print("The answer was: " + answer + ". Player 1 wins!")
```

It would be great if it could look more like this:

```
if int(guess1 == int(answer ± 1) and guess2 == int(answer ± 2))
            print("The answer was: " + answer + ". Player 1 wins!")
```

Comment: You could try `if abs(guess1 - int(answer)) == 1 and abs(guess2 - int(answer)) == 2`

Comment: What should happen when `guess1 == answer`? Besides, why are you interested in `guess2`? Why would it matter if `guess1` is right?

Comment: another way would be: `if guess1 in [answer -1, answer +1] and guess2 in [answer -2, answer+2]:`

Comment: @Selcuk if guess1 == answer, then it would say that they are correct. However, the point is to figure out which of the two guesses is closest to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> However, the point is to figure out which of the two guesses is closest to the answer.

In that case, the solution simply becomes:

```
if guess1 == guess2::
    print("It's a tie. The answer was {}".format(answer)
elif abs(guess1 - answer) < abs(guess2 - answer):
    print("Player 1 wins. The answer was {}".format(answer)
else:
    print("Player 2 wins. The answer was {}".format(answer)
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment thank you, but thank you so much. Before, my code was almost 200 lines and now it's 13

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if int(guess1) in range(answer-1, answer + 1) and (int(guess1)!= answer)
```

Comment: The OP's code specifically compares the end points of the range, not the middle.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the code. Can you kindly take off the negative voting because I'm blocked and was actually trying to remove the block by helping others? I'll really appreciate it. Thanks.